# How to Resize action Sheet element font with system font?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

[image]

Basically I want to create a Rich Text Format editor with web view.

I have retrieved all the names of the fonts in my device using the code below. I now want to select some text in my web view and apply that font on it, so I choose a Action Sheet to display all names and set the font on it. My problem is some font names are too big and all are set with same font style. I want to display the font name as the font actual style.

```
// array
NSMutableArray *fontNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// get font family
NSArray *fontFamilyNames = [UIFont familyNames];

// loop
for (NSString *familyName in fontFamilyNames)
{
    NSLog(@"Font Family Name = %@", familyName);

    // font names under family
    NSArray *names = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];

    NSLog(@"INSIDE LOOP Font Names = %@", fontNames);

    // add to array
    [fontNames addObjectsFromArray:names];
}
NSLog(@"OUT OF LOOP Font Names = %@", fontNames);

// [fontNames release];
```

And here is how I'm applying selection font on my webview selected text:

```
NSString *selectedButtonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
selectedButtonTitle = [selectedButtonTitle lowercaseString];

if ([actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Select a font"])
{        
    [printContentWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.execCommand('fontName', false, '%@')", selectedButtonTitle]];
}
```

And I want such output in my actionsheet

[image]

Comment: For this you will have to create your own custom view.

Comment: i have created a picker having all the fonts see second image, but on calling it the selected text in the web view not keep selected hence on apply change font its not working.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a web view and not `UITextView`? It does a lot of the work for you with applying different fonts to different portions. You would be able to grab the selected range of the text before showing the action sheet and then apply the chosen font to that range and re-select it if needed.

Comment: yes theMikeSwan-> i want to create Rich Text Editor having able to insert images as well,so textView is not able to do that.
i am able to set the font of text used using action sheet only,as when action sheet opens the selected text in webview keep selected and font change apply on it,but if i use custom view or either font picker,then the selected text in webview dont keep selected so the change font dont make any sense in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in your `UITableView`, since you didn't post the code of the `UIActionSheet` and `UITableView` code, I've created a project and uploaded it to a Github ([link](https://github.com/mumensh/CustomUIActionSheet)), you can find how i can manage to resize the text of the rows using the following property:

```
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Comment: hi thanks for the quick answer,right now i am not with my mac book, once i will be back after weekend i will check

Comment: Thanks its working good so i accept it as answer, but i already made it using CustomActionSheet.

Comment: oh sorry i forget to click on it! Sure you deserve it man! Enjoy coding